# Magento 2 : Icons are not showing up in magento 2.16

Tags: magento-2.1, favicons, icon

[image]

Icons are not showing up in `Magento 2.16` . I had already extended the theme and it was working perfectly.

Comment: Go for commands upgrade, di:compile, deploy once and check permissons

Comment: I couldnt found any errors while running these codes.I also changed symlink to copy in app/etc/di.xml  but not showing yhe icons

Comment: (php -f bin/magento indexer:reindex)                                       
                   (  php bin/magento cache:clean   )
                    (   php bin/magento cache:flush)

Comment: Go forr all three commands then give (chmod -Rf 777  app/ var/ pub/)

Comment: Tried ,but not showing

Comment: Can you please provide any screenshot

Comment: rm -r var/view_processed/* pub/static/frontend/*
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: go for above once